Schauder Frames in nuclear vector spaces
In recent years, the definition of frame has been extended to locally convex topological vector spaces (lcs) (1). In particular, let $X$ be a lcs and $X'$ its dual. A sequence $\big((x_n,y_n)\big)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ of elements of $X\times X'$ is said to be a Schauder frame if for any $x\in X$we have
$$x=\lim_{k\to \infty} \sum y_n(x)x_n,$$
where the limit is taken in the given topology of $X$.
Now it is well know that bases in $(F)$ nuclear spaces are very rigid: for example, a weak basis (i.e. a Schauder basis for $(X,\sigma(X,X')$) is automatically an unconditional Schauder basis and the convergence is actually absolute (2). Has any work been done on the rigidity of Schauder frames? In particular, is the previous property (weak (or strong) implies unconditional) still true?
